# Does table's OrderBy property affect Performance

Tags: ms-access

In order to improve performance it is recommended to eliminate subdatasheets defined in the table properties see [Performance Tips To Speed up your Access 2007 Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942824(v=office.12).aspx#odc_ac2007_ta_PerformanceTipsToSpeedUpYourAccessDB_TablePerformanceTips) for example.

In the table there is another property by name of `OrderBy`. Does anyone know whether this property also affects performance of queries, forms and reports using the table or is it perhaps only used when viewing records directly from the table?

Comment: to execute [order by], db engine must execute & fetch the results temporarily and then perform order by and then fetch the result set to the user.. so yes it will take some additional time!

Comment: True, but how do we know that Access executes the orderby when the table is included in a query? Perhaps the OrderBy is only used when one views the table directly.

Comment: AFAIK, SQL language isn't compatible with Quantum theory where one's "observation affects the sate of a matter" :) :) 
think this way, you have a sub-query with order by to get the recent 5 records. If db engine is not performing the [order by] you will get totally different result set.

Comment: "when one views the table directly" - Bear in mind that Access is merely a GUI to the data in a given .mdb/accdb, file albeit the First Class GUI because it is sold by MSFT. Be under no illusion: you are not seeing the 'actual' One True Version of the table, just because it is being viewed in Access. This `OrderBy` property will relate to the GUI only and will not affect generalist SQL queries.

Comment: I think you are right about the `OrderBy` not affecting queries, but not so sure about your proof, because as I mentioned in the question the `Subdatasheets` property does affect performance.

Comment: The physical order on disk will affect performance and is defined via the table's primary key (or equivalent). However, you do need to be smart about this and the performance guide you link to has some pretty dumb advice ("Primary Key Should be One Field and Numeric").

Comment: OK, but in my question I am using Access. So I still need to know where `OrderBy` affects performance when I am using Access as the development tool.

Comment: The clustered index (physical ordering on disk) will affect performance whether or not you are using Access.

Answer (score 1):

The OrderBy property of  table object is mostly there to apply a default sort when you open a table in the interface. It does not apply to queries involving this table.

From the official doc [OrderBy Property](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OrderBy-Property-C6EBD0C0-76DC-4A0E-981D-FD44428AEA7C) :

> Note: When a new object is created, it inherits the RecordSource , Filter ,
>   OrderBy, and OrderByOn properties of the table or query it was created
>   from. **For forms and reports, inherited filters aren't automatically
>   applied when an object is opened**.

So when you create your report or form, if the recordsource is the table on which you defined an OrderBy, the report or form will inherit this specific OrderBy value :

- If you don't touch the OrderBy Property of your object, yes it will affect the performance because the OrderBy automatically inherited will persist.
- If you manually delete the OrderBy property value automatically inherited when you created your object, no it won't affect the performance because the OrderBy will be gone for good.

For queries that's different as you will see the OrderBy in the SQL or the query interface and you can just remove it